# Linq to sql select records based on child records

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am having an issue trying to get this statment to work. I am trying to filter a parent set of records based off of a one to many child relationship table. I get an error that I cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type. I would like to stay with a Linq solution if possible.

```
result = db.ParentTable.Where(r => r.ChildTable.Where(c => c.ChildField == value));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you're after, but maybe this is it:

```
db.ParentTable.Where(r => r.ChildTable.Any(c => c.ChildField == value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using query syntax:

```
result = from parent in db.ParentTable
         from child in parent.ChildTable
         where child.ChildField == value
         select parent;
```